# Is it possible to automatically sign in to the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

Each time (at the beginning of the session) I buy or update an app in the mac app store I have to sign in.
I want to be automatically signed in, like I am in the iTunes Store.

I couldn't find any "remember password in keychain" option.
Did I miss an option somewhere? Or is there any way so I get signed in automatically?

Comment: Do you *really* want anyone else who happens to be using your computer to be able to spend $1,000 of your money with a couple of mouse clicks?

Comment: gl, i live alone and i still have a password on my computer

Comment: I have to agree with the other comments. Allowing the use of the Apple ID without password would be senseless. Although the way it works could be improved by requiring a password only for new transactions instead of asking for a password for updates and free apps.

Comment: Yes, I really want this. Imho it's not more dangerous than all the other possibly saved passwords like itunes Store or Steam. Safari can save passwords for amazon, paypal, my bank, my health records or the online tax declaration center. Even Xcode allows me to save the password for the developer portal. Somebody with bad intentions and access to my computer could just reset the password of my Apple ID, Mail.app doesn't need a password. But there is one protection against this: don't let anybody use your user account. That's how I handle this :-)

Comment: I second @MatthiasBauch, I have moved around and ended up with accounts in different countries. Un-like for iOS you must logout, change store location, then login in order to update application from the store

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this option doesn't exist. (Perhaps because it would be to some extent a security risk.) You might remain signed in for a short period of time, but you can't automatically log yourself in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your'e right, Think about if someone else got onto the app store and downloaded thousands of dollars worth of software?? iTunes is a little harder to do that so quickly.

Comment: Thank You. Though I'm pretty sure that the security risk of choosing an easier to remember password is higher than being logged in forever on a personal computer. If I would not have 1Password on my iPad and the Mac the password of my Apple ID would most likely be something like `hunter2`. Actually it was something similar before I got 1Password ;-)

Comment: I actually think it would increase security if I had the password stored in an encrypted keyfile and not in a text document for cut'n'paste as i have it now.